# How is miniconda getting added to my powershell $env:path?

Tags: windows, powershell, python, path

When I check my user and system PATH variables, neither of them has the Miniconda path included.

However, if I open up a powershell prompt and run `echo $env:path` I see that this includes the contents of the user and system PATH, as well as a number of paths for miniconda:

```
C:\Users\9279\Miniconda3
C:\Users\9279\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\9279\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\Users\9279\Miniconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\9279\Miniconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\9279\Miniconda3\bin
C:\Users\9279\Miniconda3\condabin
```

If I run a `cat $profile`, I only have some stuff related to posh prompt:

```
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Set-PoshPrompt -Theme "C:\Users\9279\desktop\TEMp\custom_posh_theme\hotstick-python.minimal.omp.json"
```

So how is Miniconda getting added to my path?

Comment: you have multiple profiles that take effect on your session. one for the every combo of user/all-users/host/all-hosts . the `$Profile` variable defaults to showing the `CurrentUserCurrentHost` profile. i recommend you check the others. [*grin*]

Comment: How do I check the others?

Comment: take a look at the others that are in the $Var you looked at ... >>> `$profile | Select-Object -Property *` <<<

Comment: `$profile.psobject.Properties.Value | % {"===""$_""===";cat $_ -EA 0}` is a simple _dirty_ way…